# Finding a Rational univariate representation (RUR) for a Polynomial System

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

According to Wikipedia, [a RUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations#Rational_univariate_representation) of a zero-dimensional system consists in a linear combination of the variables, $x_0$ 
called ''separating variable'', and a system of equations
:
\begin{cases}
h(x_0)=0\\
x_1=g_1(x_0)/g_0(x_0)\\
\quad\vdots\\
x_n=g_n(x_0)/g_0(x_0),
\end{cases}

where $h$ is a univariate polynomial in $x_0$ of degree $D$ and $g_0, \dots, g_n$ are univariate polynomials in $x_0$ of degree less than $D$.

Is there a way to find such a system in Mathematica, given a list of polynomials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recall offhand how these are computed in general. For the case of distinct roots I can illustrate one method. I'll take the example in that Wikipedia article.

We have polynomials as below.

```
polys = {x^2-1, (x-1)*(y-1), y^2-1};
```

We take as separating element `t = (x-y)/2`.

```
seppoly = t-(x-y)/2;
```

First compute the polynomial referred to as `h(t)`. Then take its derivative.

```
tpoly = 
 First[GroebnerBasis[Join[polys, {seppoly}], t, {x, y}, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]]
dtpoly = D[tpoly, t];

(* Out[132]= -t + t^3 *)
```

Now call that derivative `den` and find "numerator" polynomials `g1` and `g2` such that `den*x=g1` and similar for `y`. I use `GroebnerBasis` with a monomial order that is efficient for eliminating `{x,y,den}` and in effect solving for `{g1,g2}` in terms of `t`.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[
  Join[polys, {seppoly, dtpoly - den}, den*{x, y} - {g1, g2}], {g1, 
   g2, t}, {x, y, den}, 
  MonomialOrder -> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 
     0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0, -1, 0}}]

(* Out[161]= {-t + t^3, 1 + g2 + 2 t - t^2, 1 + g1 - 2 t - t^2} *)
```

The numerators are readily recovered.

```
numerators = {g1, g2} /. 
  First[Solve[Rest[gb] == 0, {g1, g2}]]

(* Out[164]= {-1 + 2 t + t^2, -1 - 2 t + t^2} *)
```

The rational univariate representation:

```
rur = Join[{tpoly}, {x, y} - numerators/dtpoly]

(* Out[167]= {-t + t^3, -((-1 + 2 t + t^2)/(-1 + 3 t^2)) + 
  x, -((-1 - 2 t + t^2)/(-1 + 3 t^2)) + y} *)
```

Comment: Is there a general way to find a separating element? Or does one just have to try different things?

Comment: A random linear combination of the variables will be a separating element with probability 1.

Comment: Could you talk about how you came up with the matrix you used in `MonomialOrder`?

Comment: @J.M'sTech... (First, thanks for fixing the typo) It is basically a block order with the elimination variables handled in a degree-reverse-lax block. The lower block is constructed to soleve for two variables in terms of a third, and those two are weighted equally for efficiency. Provided we have a correct separating element this will work since both will end up as linear leading monomials. I could have used something closer to the matrix form of `EliminationOrder` and maybe that would in general be more efficient for the purposes at hand.

Comment: This seems a bit complicated for the user lambda. On the other hand, the competition provides  an off-shelf  command https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner/RationalUnivariateRepresentation

Comment: @florin I should add this to the function repository.