# Can we ask Mathematica if a reduction of a system to one scalar equation in one variable+ rational representations of the other variables exists?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra, groebner-bases

Nonlinear determined  systems have typically several solutions involving square or higher order  roots. Instead of solving them, it may be more profitable to reduce them to smaller systems with fewer variables, accompanied by rational formulas for the other variables. For example the system with three equations

```
ss = bs - s (\[Mu] + \[Gamma]s) + 
   is i + \[Gamma]r r - \[Beta]s s i (1 + \[Xi] i) + \[Delta]q i s;
        ii = 
  i (\[Beta]s s (1 + \[Xi] i) + \[Beta]r r (1 + \[Xi] i) - (\[Mu] + \
\[Delta] + ir + is) +
                  \[Delta]q i);
        rr = 
  br + \[Gamma]s s + 
   ir i - \[Beta]r r i (1 + \[Xi] i) - (\[Mu] + \[Gamma]r) r + \
\[Delta]q i  r;
        dyn = {ii, ss, rr}; X = {i, s, r}; par = 
 Complement[Variables[dyn], X]; eq = Thread[dyn == 0]; 
    csr = Solve[Drop[eq, 1], {s, r}][[1]]
    pol = Numerator[Together[dyn[[1]] /. csr]]
```

was easily reduced to a rational substitution csr and a scalar equation pol=0. On the other hand the direct solution

```
Solve[eq, X]
```

leads to embarassingly long results. In this example I searched myself for the reduction. Can we ask Mathematica if such a reduction to one scalar equation + rational representations exists? And if not, find a  representation where the reduced system is of minimal degree?

Added: Based on @David G. Stork suggestion, I added a script Grobpol which does the job if the user inputs the correct variable to be kept (first) and the equation to be removed (first).

```
    Grobpol[mod_, ind_, cn_ : {}] := Module[{dyn, X, par, eq, elim},
         dyn = mod[[1]]; X = mod[[2]]; par = mod[[3]]; 
      eq = Thread[dyn == 0]; elim = Complement[Range[Length[X]], ind];
         pol = 
       Collect[GroebnerBasis[Numerator[Together[dyn /. cn]], 
         Join[par, X[[ind]]], X[[elim]]], X[[ind]]];
         ratsub = Solve[Drop[eq, ind], {s, r}][[1]]; {ratsub, pol}
      ]

ind = {1};
mod = {dyn, X, par};
Timing[Grobpol[mod, ind]]
```

In principle, one can further program an answer to my question by running over all possibilities of indices, and, if no answer, replace ind by a pair of indices, etc. However, my program already takes much longer than the uncapsulated direct solution. Is it possible to speed it up? And most importantly, does Mathematica already offer solutions to this  question? And if not, might it be a worthwhile addition to its capabilities?

Comment: Check `GroebnerBasis`.

Comment: Also see if what you are seeking is the “rational univariate representation” (RUR) of a polynomial system. It’s related to a Groebner basis, if memory serves.

Comment: Also might want to check [this prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216749/51). (It seems the author forgot he once knew how to code this sort of thing.)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortuately, it seems implementing some form of RUR in Mathematica, Maple, etc, is still more of an open question. This may not be that difficult. Note that in appications the need to use a linear combination will have probably measure 0. In most applications it will be one of the variables itself that will allow the lowest degree represntation.